# Scala: NoSuchMethodException when invoking mutable.ArrayBuffer（List，Int)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to invoke(List,Int) by reflecting, it's my code:

```
class TagCalculation {
  def test(arg1: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon[Any],arg2: java.lang.Integer) = "test mix2"
}
val getTest =  new TagCalculation

val arg1 : scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any] = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer()
arg1 += Array(1,2,3)

arg1 += 4

val argtypes4 = arg1.map(_.getClass)
val method4 = getTest.getClass.getMethod("test", argtypes4: _*)
method4.invoke(getTest,calcParamsArray.asInstanceOf[Seq[Object]]: _*)
```

but method4 would some errors:

> scala> val argtypes4 = arg1.map(*.getClass) argtypes4:
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Class[*]] = ArrayBuffer(class [I,
>   class java.lang.Integer)
>
> scala> val method4 = getTest.getClass.getMethod("test", argtypes4: _*)
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $iwC$$iwC$TagCalculation.test([I,
>   java.lang.Integer)    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1678)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:35)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:40)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:42)

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array is a different type than :: that is of type List. This change should work

```
class TagCalculation {
  def test(arg1: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon[Any],arg2: java.lang.Integer) = "test mix2"
}
val getTest =  new TagCalculation

val arg1 : scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any] = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer()
arg1 += List(1,2,3)

arg1 += 4

val argtypes4 = arg1.map(_.getClass)
val method4 = getTest.getClass.getMethod("test", argtypes4: _*)
method4.invoke(getTest,calcParamsArray.asInstanceOf[Seq[Object]]: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an `Array[Int]`

```
arg1 += Array(1,2,3)
```

to the `test` method but the `test` method is expecting `arg1: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon[Any]`

So changing the `test` function to

```
def test(arg1: Array[Int],arg2: java.lang.Integer) = "test mix2"
```

should work too

Comment: great to hear that :)